# store File in Redux and retrieve it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui

I'm using material-ui-dropzone to upload a file array and store in redux

But while I retrieve it from redux state the it is not of type "File" and in devtools shows as

[image]

Now I try to read a file

```
const reader = new FileReader();
fileName = mydatafromstate[mydatafromstate.length - 1].name
// file reading finished successfully
reader.addEventListener('loadend', function(e) {
  // contents of file in variable
  let filecontent = e.target.result;

  console.log(filecontent);
});
reader.readAsText(mydatafromstate[mydatafromstate.length - 1])
```

I get the following error

```
error validating against api:  TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.
```

My redux state also looks like this

[image]

How do I properly store File in Redux and retrieve it as File and retrieve its contents?

Answer (score 0):

this may not be the best answer and i am just trying to help if i can.
As far as i know, we update the redux store by dispatching. In other word you will need to pass an action and a value to reducer.
I think after receiving you file successfully, try something like:

```
dispatch{(
    type: "action-name", // give it a proper name like reading-file
    content: "here add your file content", // pass your array 
  });
```

then, you will need to define an action in your reducer to update your global state.

For files, I think you may need to download the files into the public or upload folder and just give the files path to redux.